# C++ map with pointer value

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I try to read a dictionary file, in which each line contains word-id, word and frequency separated by a whitespace. The problem is that the map used to store words turned out have same value. I very appreciate if you can help me.

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    int count;
    char* word;
} WORD;

//read file
std::map<int, WORD*> readWordMap(char* file_name)
{
    std::ifstream infile(file_name, std::ifstream::in);
    std::cout<<"word map read file:"<<file_name<<std::endl;
    if (! infile) {
        std::cerr<<"oops! unable to open file "<<file_name<<std::endl;
        exit(-1);
     }
     std::map<int, WORD*> map;
     std::vector<std::string> tokens;
     std::string line;
     char word[100];
     int size;
     while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
         size =  (int)split(line, tokens, ' ');
         WORD* entry = (WORD*) malloc(sizeof(WORD*));
         entry->id = atoi(tokens[0].c_str());
         entry->count = atoi(tokens[2].c_str());
         strcpy(word, tokens[1].c_str());
         entry->word = word;

         map[entry->id] = entry;
         std::cout<< entry->id<<" "<<entry->word<<" "<<entry->count<<std::endl;

      }
      infile.close();
      std::cout<<map.size()<<std::endl;
      std::map<int, WORD*>::const_iterator it;
      for (it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); it++) {
           std::cout<<(it->first)<<" "<<(it->second->word)<<std::endl;

      }

      return map;
}

//split string by a delimiter
size_t split(const std::string &txt, std::vector<std::string> &strs, char ch)
{
    size_t pos = txt.find( ch );
    size_t initialPos = 0;
    strs.clear();

    while( pos != std::string::npos ) {
        strs.push_back( txt.substr( initialPos, pos - initialPos + 1 ) );
        initialPos = pos + 1;

        pos = txt.find( ch, initialPos );
    } 

   strs.push_back( txt.substr( initialPos, std::min( pos, txt.size() ) - initialPos + 1      ) );

   return strs.size();
}
```

Data file:

```
2 I  1
3 gave  1
4 him  1
5 the  3
6 book  3
7 .  3
8 He  2
9 read  1
10 loved  1
```

result:

```
2 I  1
3 gave  1
4 him  1
5 the  3
6 book  3
7 .  3
8 He  2
9 read  1
10 loved  1
map size:9
2 loved 
3 loved 
4 loved 
5 loved 
6 loved 
7 loved 
8 loved 
9 loved 
10 loved
```

Comment: I highly suggest you kill the pointers and just use `std::string` in place of `char *` and `std::map<int, WORD>` in place of `std::map<int, WORD *>`.

Comment: Also ``WORD* entry = (WORD*) malloc(sizeof(WORD*));`` is wrong. Should be `WORD* entry = (WORD*) malloc(sizeof(WORD));` instead

Comment: @chris thank you a lot, I have replaced the `WORD* and char*` with `WORD std::string` respectively.

Comment: @Xaqq thanks, I have corrected it. But the result is still same. @M M.    Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: Yeah, I didnt expect that it would fix your problem, but having memory error can't help :D. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WORD* entry = (WORD*) malloc(sizeof(WORD*));
```

allocates a `WORD pointer` not a whole `WORD` struct.

The compiler keeps allocating entry put it is **not initalized to anything** (*they are all pointing to some random address which doesnt even belong to your program possibly.* ) and you add that pointer to the map repeatedly. So all firsts of your map are pointing to the same location (*coincidentaly*). It should be

```
WORD* entry = new WORD;
```

---

This is a cleaner way of doing it

```
struct WORD{
    int id;
    int count;
    std::string word;
};
```

---

```
while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
     WORD* entry = new WORD;
     std::istringstream iss(line);

     iss >> entry->id >> entry->word >> entry->count;
     map[entry->id] = entry;
     std::cout<< entry->id<<" "<<entry->word<<" "<<entry->count<<std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: thank very much. it works. But I try to print the allocated addresses of  `WORD*`, which are pointing to different locations. `0x100100ae0
0x100100ab0
0x100100c20
0x100100c90
0x100100d00
0x100100d70
0x100100de0
0x100100e50
0x100100ec0`

Comment: @user2293003 You mean you tried to print them in your original code? or in my version?

Comment: @user2293003 Don't use `malloc` in C++. Use `new`. Use `stingstreams` when you can. And avoid raw pointers when you can.

Comment: Well it might be that the compiler allocates them in different places. But **they all point to the same address**. Their value is undefined since they are not pointing to anything valid. This is called **Undefined Behavior**. Which means there is really no guarantee of what happens. Things can go any way. Anyway I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to allocate memory for `WORD::word` before `strcpy`. And you are assigning the address of `char word[100]` to all items of the map which is same for all of them.

And it's better to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of C-style strings. In addition you can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert strings to integers. Try this:

```
struct WORD{
    int id;
    int count;
    std::string word;
};

std::map<int, WORD> readWordMap(const std::string &file_name)
{
     ...
     std::map<int, WORD> map;
     ...

     while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
         ...

         WORD entry;
         entry.id = std::stoi(tokens[0]);
         entry.count = std::stoi(tokens[2]);
         entry.word = tokens[1];

         map[entry.id] = entry;

         ...
      }
      infile.close();
      ...
}
```